# problem with installation of Java JDK 11

Tags: java, openjdk

```
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openjdk-11-jdk : Depends: openjdk-11-jre (= 11~24-1~18.04)
                  Depends: openjdk-11-jdk-headless (= 11~24-1~18.04)
 openjdk-11-jre-headless : Conflicts: oracle-java11-installer but 11.0.1-2~linuxuprising1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Please help how to resolve

Comment: Have you tried `apt --fix-broken install` as advised?

Comment: You cannot install oracle Java and openjdk at the same time as for now.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-lts/+bug/1782630

Answer (score 2):

try,

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

if above command does not help then try to install oracle JDK with following steps.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

To setup the environment variable

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

then check whether JDK installed properly.

```
java
javac
```

Comment: Installing Oracle JDK does not solve the problem of installing OpenJDK.

Answer (score 1):

Please can you try and see which jdk will install with this:

```
sudo apt install default-jre
```

If you don't like the version don't install it. The last time I test it It was build of java 10.0.2 but it was compatible with java 11 (I dont remeber clearly). Nevertheless in the future it will be changes to java 11.

Check here for more info: [Why is OpenJDK 10 packaged as openjdk-11-*?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037646/why-is-openjdk-10-packaged-as-openjdk-11)