# Which Java version am I using?

Tags: java, openjdk

On Lubuntu 18.04, I though I am using Java 10, because

```
$ javac -version
javac 10.0.2

$ java -version
openjdk version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.4)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.4, mixed mode)
```

But I am not sure, because I seem to use Java 11. I am confused. Thanks.

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1101      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1101      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 

$ sudo update-alternatives --config javac
There are 2 choices for the alternative javac (providing /usr/bin/javac).

  Selection    Path                                          Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac   1101      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac   1101      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac    1081      manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:       

$ realpath /usr/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java

$ realpath /usr/bin/javac
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is OpenJDK 10 packaged as openjdk-11-\*?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037646/why-is-openjdk-10-packaged-as-openjdk-11) That's a known issue in 18.04. Read [muru's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1037655/816190) to know.