# When I try to install OpenJDK 11, OpenJDK 10 got installed

Tags: apt, software-installation, openjdk

I used the below apt command to install OpenJDK 11

```
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk
```

But, OpenJDK 10 got installed, result of `java --version`

```
openjdk 10.0.1 2018-04-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.1+10-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.1+10-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1, mixed mode)
```

After `apt update` Output of `sudo apt-cache policy openjdk-11-jdk`

```
openjdk-11-jdk:
  Installed: 10.0.1+10-3ubuntu1
  Candidate: 10.0.1+10-3ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 10.0.1+10-3ubuntu1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

How to install OpenJDK 11?

Ubuntu version: 18.04

Comment: Such inconsistency [happened](https://askubuntu.com/q/1037646/816190) couple of years ago which was fixed after some months. Also, as per [Ubuntu Package search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=openjdk-11-jdk&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all), unless you're using 18.04 running on non amd64/i386 device, the mentioned build isn't available in any supported release. Did you run `sudo apt update` before installing the package? Please [edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy openjdk-11-jdk`. Also, mention the Ubuntu version you're using.

Comment: @Kulfy updated the question

Comment: Seems Ubuntu never updated JDK in main. What do you see under Updates in Software and updates app? Is there any option like bionic-security (I'm currently on 20.04, thus, cannot verify)? Is that enables? What is the output of `grep security /etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: @Kulfy  selected everything under updates in Software and updates app. And now I'm able to install OpenJdk 11.

Comment: @Kulfy Thanks for the help

Comment: I have posted an answer. If that helped, you can mark that as accepted by clicking on grey check icon which would appear on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is a [known issue](https://askubuntu.com/q/1037646/816190) in OpenJDK 11 version 10.0.1+10-3ubuntu1 provided by bionic/main repository. An updated version 11.0.8+10-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 is available in  [bionic-updates](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/openjdk-11-jdk) as well as [bionic-security](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/openjdk-11-jdk) which wasn't pushed in bionic/main. You may consider enabling at least one of the said repository to install the updated version.

You can enable them from *Software and Updates→Updates* or append them directly in `sources.list` using [`tee`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html). For that run,

```
echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Once done, run `sudo apt update` and retry installing/updating OpenJDK 11.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that there already was a JDK installed and installing new one didn't automatically set it to current version.

Here is a link to the post describing how to set Java version: [Switch between multiple java versions](https://askubuntu.com/q/740757/968480)

---

This is what I have found working:

`apt install` doesn't configure the Java version, if there already exist one.

If the openjdk-11 got installed, you can switch to this like that:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

This shows you a table of JDK's installed, pick the the correct one from the list with enter.

Also, you might want to change `$JAVA_HOME` environment variable, to  by running:

```
export JAVA_HOME="$(jrunscript -e java.lang.System.out.println(java.lang.System.getProperty("java.home"));')"
```

Comment: only one version of java is installed.